Can't find Azure deployment app service files in kudu
My files in Visual Studio are corrupted, but I have previously successfully deployed it to Azure using the web service.
I'm trying to clone the project by downloading the wwwroot directory from kudu, but all my .cs and .cshtml files are not in the wwwroot directory, however the website is still running and working. Below is the screenshot of some of the files in the /site/wwwroot directory and my local project folder.


Local folder structure:


As discussed in the previous comments, please add the deployment details in the question.I am able to get the deployed files using dotpeek decompiler.


Cant find azure depolyment app service files in kudu

The WebApp files(.cs/.aspx/.cshtml) deployed from Visual Studio to the Azure App service will be compiled as dll/pdb and exe with the WebApp name.


My files in visual studios are corrupted


You can download the dll files(using WINSCP/FTP) and use them in your Visual Studio to work locally.


OR
Another workaround is to download dotpeek (.NET Compiler) and use the dll file to get the complete project.

Open the downloaded dll file from the dotpeek.



Right click on the dll and click on Export to project.



All the files will be downloaded to the selected folder.


